# Azure fileshare path with container instance volume path mapping using ARM templates

Tags: azure, containers, azure-rm-template, allure, azure-files

Has anyone had success in mapping Azure fileshare path mapping with Container volume path. I'm specifically looking for Allure Docker container mounting in azure and mapping container volume path to Azurefile share path.

I have used ARM templates and also yml files. but no where I could find mounting volume paths defined or explained in Azure docs online.

Also I saw an option where one can create their own container and host it in Azure container registry and then they can use docker-compose file to map the volume paths. Which is not I'm after. I dont want to host container in ACR. I'm using third party container always.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "containerGroups_tst_tf_allure_report_api_aci_name": {
      "defaultValue": "tst-tf-allure-report-api-aci",
      "type": "String"
    }
  },
  "variables": {},
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups",
      "apiVersion": "2019-12-01",
      "name": "[parameters('containerGroups_tst_tf_allure_report_api_aci_name')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "properties": {
        "sku": "Standard",
        "containers": [
          {
            "name": "[parameters('containerGroups_tst_tf_allure_report_api_aci_name')]",
            "properties": {
              "image": "frankescobar/allure-docker-service",
              "ports": [
                {
                  "protocol": "TCP",
                  "port": 5050
                }
              ],
              "volumeMounts": [
                {
                  "name": "filesharevolume",
                  "mountPath": "/mnt/acishare/projects"
                }
              ],
              "environmentVariables": [
                {
                  "name": "CHECK_RESULTS_EVERY_SECONDS",
                  "value": 1
                },
                {
                  "name": "KEEP_HISTORY",
                  "value": 1
                },
                {
                  "name": "KEEP_HISTORY_LATEST",
                  "value": 25
                }
              ],
              "resources": {
                "requests": {
                  "memoryInGB": 1,
                  "cpu": 1
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "initContainers": [],
        "restartPolicy": "OnFailure",
        "osType": "Linux",
        "ipAddress": {
          "ports": [
            {
              "protocol": "TCP",
              "port": 5050
            }
          ],
          "type": "Public"
        },
        "volumes": [
          {
            "name": "filesharevolume",
            "azureFile": {
              "shareName": "acishare",
              "storageAccountName": "acistoragev1",
              "storageAccountKey": "zzzxxxxxxxxxddddddddddddddd"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright after debugging alot with Azure container and Fileshare, I got the answer finally.
The "mountPath" is bascially the container volume path which you want to map back to Azure Fileshare directory. But the path does not need to exists on the fileshare directory. just the root name /acishare should match to your fileshare directory.
In my case above it is /acishare/projects. After fixing this I can see the volume is correctly copying files to /acishare/projects directory and I can restart container or re-create container, the files are retained and re-sycned back to the container.

Comment: Just copy my answer and accept yourself? You are so excellent!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problems with your ARM template and it works fine on my side. When you map the Azure file share on the container, then you can see the files in that path both where. But you need to note that the path must be a new one or there no files exist in that path before mapping. Azure file share will hide the files existing before. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-volume-azure-files#deploy-container-and-mount-volume---resource-manager) is the example about map Azure file share to ACI.

Comment: I dont see the container files mounted in the fileshare. I started container and adding files in to the container,but they are never show in AZ files hare. Just to let you know the docker container (frankescobar/allure-docker-service), is mapping the volume at /app/projects. this is path I want to map to azfile share.